# Usage Of && and ||

Tags: batch-file

I have this code:

```
start searchForThis
:a
tasklist /v|find "searchForThis"&&goto a||goto b
:b
del searchForThis
```

I want this code to loop as long as "searchForThis" is found and when it is no longer found, it is deleted. Could somebody tell me what's wrong? This code gives random output, deleting sometimes and ignoring it other times.

Comment: What do you mean with `del searchForThis` ? Do you mean killing the task Searchforthis ?

Comment: Delete the file "searchForThis"

Comment: But with tasklist you can't find a file but a task who is running on your machine

Comment: @sachadee As I see it, he wants to delete a file, when it doesn't run anymore. user3093536: what do you mean with "random output"?

Comment: @Stephan, sometimes it deletes the file and other times it doesn't

Comment: does it go to `:b`? if yes, a `timeout -t 1 >nul` between `:b` and `del...` may help.

Comment: It seems to only go to :b sometimes, I'll try adding that in

Comment: The result is the same, it differs each time I run it

Comment: could you add an echo before the del, to check if :b is reached each time or not? Also what happened if :b is not reached? It loops endlessly or it exits?

Comment: It helps to show actual code.  You could be omitting anything and so wasting everybodies time.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I see no reason to escape the special chars. Also a few spaces would help:

```
tasklist /v |find "searchForThis" && goto a || goto b
```

Comment: I placed it in front of "echo" at first, but this doesn't change anything.